# Applescript: How to get full path of the current finder window open?

Tags: applescript

I have this script, it works fine, but it doesn't give me the full link when I am opening a finder window on the network, which should start with 'Volumes', how to make it detect it?

```
    tell application "Finder"
            if exists window 1 then
                set currentDir to POSIX path of ((target of front Finder window) as text)
            else
                set currentDir to POSIX path of (path to desktop folder)
            end if
    end tell
        log currentDir
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists Finder window 1 then
        set currentDir to target of Finder window 1 as alias
    else
        set currentDir to desktop as alias
    end if
end tell
log POSIX path of currentDir
```